# Sources of cardano rest api

Tags: cardano-api

While testing some  tangocrypto api , it is asking for "collection_id" which I don't know what is it.
So are there any Rest API providers other than (tangocrypto.com, blockFrost.com and opencnft.io)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, here's the documentation for the Tangocrypto API:

https://www.tangocrypto.com/api-reference/#/operations/nft-collection

The collection_id here is just the ID of an NFT Collection that you can create on the platform. *(You receive it in the response when you create one via the "Create NFT collection" endpoint or list your collections via "List NFT collections".)*

If you're looking to find assets on the blockchain, e.g. via policy id you can look at this endpoint:

https://www.tangocrypto.com/api-reference/#/operations/get-asset-by-policy

Secondly, here's another alternative you could look at, if needed: https://dandelion.link/

Comment: but , How can I fetch all data of NFT's like buy Price , sold price . rarity, meta data through wallet address in one api ?

Comment: The metadata is there, but the others are marketplace specific. Haven't used it but looks like the one you mentioned, opencnft.io, has aggregated lots of data, eg floor prices, traits for rarity etc. You can try it out in their docs: https://api.opencnft.io/1/#/Policy/PublicController_getPolicyFloorPrice. To get them "by address" you'd have to use any of the other APIs to fetch assets sitting at it and then get the NFT data for each.

Comment: I am doing the same process as you mentioned above. I want to fetch NFT data through users wallet address, so for that I am using (cardano-mainnet.tangocrypto.com /{app_id}/v1/addresses/{address}/assets) and this gives me policy_id and asset name which I am using in (api.opencnft.io/1/asset{asset}, where asset is "policy_id + asset name") which gives me some data i want and another api (api.opencnft.io/1/asset{asset}/tx) also gives some useful data. Problem is that all these Processes are taking time

Comment: Ok, I don’t know of any API that can get you the data faster unfortunately. The fastest way is probably to run your own node, query the chain locally und monitor the marketplace contracts yourself. I don't have experience setting that up though.